How to calculate monthly average balance based on yearly average balance
I have a sample table as below:



Average from 01012024 to 30062024
Average from 01012024 to 31072024
Average from 01012024 to 11082024
Average from 01072024 to 31072024
Average from 01082024 to 11082024




275,243
275,882
275,295
279,633
263,933



So I have average balance from 01012024 to 30062024; 31072024 and 11082024 (yearly average). Then I want to calculate average balance of each month (July and August) based on yearly average and date numbers of each month.
What should I do in this case.
Thank you.

use averageifs() with criteria  greater than one date and less than another

Just to make sure, "Average to" numbers are not cumulative totals ("Total to"), right?

@SolarMike: Hi, thank for your reply. Average to 30062024; 31072024; 11082024 is calculated by daily amount from 01012024 to 30062024; 31072024 and 11082024. And now I want to calculate average amount from 01072024 to 31072024; 01082024 to 11082024  (but I don't know daily amount). Thank you. Can you reply by an answer?

As I understood you need a result as of this workaround:
For clearer and shorter formula, I applied a column for the count of days in the period. (=B2-A2+1).
=(VLOOKUP(B5,B$2:D$6,2,FALSE)*VLOOKUP(B5,B$2:D$6,3,FALSE)-VLOOKUP(EOMONTH(B5,-1),B$2:D$6,2,FALSE)*VLOOKUP(EOMONTH(B5,-1),B$2:D$6,3,FALSE))/D5

With 365  in cell D5 and drag down
=LET(num,B$2:B$6-A$2:A$6+1,
tab,HSTACK(B$2:C$6,num),
(VLOOKUP(B5,tab,2,FALSE)*VLOOKUP(B5,tab,3,FALSE)-VLOOKUP(EOMONTH(B5,-1),tab,2,FALSE)*
 VLOOKUP(EOMONTH(B5,-1),tab,3,FALSE))/(B5-A5+1))



thank for your supports. I think I found solutions as below:

With average from 01072024 to 31072024 I will use (Average Balance from 01012024 to 31072024 * Days No from 01012024 to 31072024 - Average Balance from 01012024 to 30062024 * Days No from 01012024 to 30062024)/Days No from 01072024 to 31072024 by below formula:
=+(C3*SUM(B1:C1)-B3*SUM(B1:B1))/C1

In my case it will be: (275,882 * (182 + 31) - 275,243 * 182)/31 = 279,633.
